# Problem with Python inside a Google Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have put the following code into a Python 3.8 Google Cloud Function.  All I did was update the "Hello-World" example and added the import line at the top.  I'm so confused as I literally just started to use GCP this week and I thought it'd be easier to set up a connection into a bucket.  The error I'm seeing in the logs is below the code.

```
from google.cloud import storage
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

The error messages are:

```
2020-11-20 15:22:20.289 MSTCloud FunctionsUpdateFunctionus-central1:faautoingestiongcp*******@gmail.com {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, methodName: google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction, resourceName: projects/reference-rain-293921/locations/us-central1/functions/faautoingestiongcp, serviceName: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com, s…

{@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, methodName: google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction, resourceName: projects/reference-rain-293921/locations/us-central1/functions/faautoingestiongcp, serviceName: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com, s…
```

Comment: How do you deploy the function?

Answer (score 0):

1. `mkdir ooo`
2. `cd ooo`
3. `cat main.py`

```
from google.cloud import storage
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

4. `cat requirements.txt`

```
google-cloud-storage
```

5. `gcloud functions deploy hello_world --runtime python37 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated`

```
entryPoint: hello_world
httpsTrigger:
  url: https://us-central1-xxxx.cloudfunctions.net/hello_world
ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
labels:
  deployment-tool: cli-gcloud
name: projects/xxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/functions/hello_world
runtime: python37

.....................
us: ACTIVE
timeout: 60s
updateTime: '2020-11-21T12:50:41.095Z'
versionId: '2'
```

Everything worked as expected.

[Quickstart: Using the gcloud Command-Line Tool](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart)